# In Django, how to collect user's input?

Tags: django

I have a question about Django.

I have two webpages. User input data in the first webpage, and then the second webpage provides the user something that is selected by user's input in the first webpage.

My question is how to collect user's input in a view class so that the data can be used by another view class.

Here is the code for the first webpage which is to let users input their program name:

```
args = {}
class Program(forms.Form):
    program_text = forms.CharField(label="Your Program", help_text="e.g. History", required = True)


def Choose_Program(request):
    form = Program(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        args["program"] = form.cleaned_data.get("program_text")
    context = {"form":form}
return render(request, "program.html", context)
```

Here is the code for the second webpage which is to let users choose their prescribed courses according to the program name they input in the first webpage:

```
PRE_COURSES = find_prescribed(args["major_program"])

class PrescribedCourses(forms.Form):
    pre_courses = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label = "Prescribed Courses"
                                        choices = PRE_COURSES,
                                        widget = forms.CheckBoxSelectMultiple,
                                        required = True)
def choose_pre_courses(request):
    form = PrescribedCourses(request)
    if form.is_valid():
        args["courses_taken"] = form.cleaned_data.get("pre_courses")
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "Choose_Pre_Courses.html", context)
```

So actually I want to use the dictionary args to store the input from users. But it cannot work.

Thanks!

Comment: If my answer helped you accept it, please. It's a good practice in StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**: What you are missing is the concept of [`models`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/) in order to preserve the state of your app. Have you completed the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/)? Once you completed, you can answer your question by yourself!

The concept in general is this: You get data from user from the 1st webpage, you validate them, you store them in your database (aka `model`). In the 2nd webpage, you retrieve the same data (according to some parameters) from your model (database) and then you handle them as you wish. Hope you understand it!

You collect user's input via forms. Each form submission has its own method of submit (`GET`, `POST` etc.). I could go on with forms but thats not the thing here.

Better read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) in order to familiarize yourself with forms.

Also, if you mind, could you share a snippet of your code so people here can help you!

Comment: Thanks for your advice!